# MySQL results yesterday, last week, last month and last year

Tags: mysql, recordset

my datefield (`artists.onlineDate`) is yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

right now I got:

```
-- Today
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE DATE(artists.onlineDate) = CURDATE()
-- Current Week
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE WEEK(artists.onlineDate, 3) = WEEK(CURDATE(), 3)
-- Current Month
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE MONTH(artists.onlineDate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
-- Current Year
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE YEAR(artists.onlineDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

But what I need is exact: Yesterday, Last Week, Last Month, Last Year

I try to explain. if we got wednesday, and I use `SELECT * FROM artists WHERE DATE(artists.onlineDate) = CURDATE()`, then I get monday to wednesday.

I would like to have the monday to sunday of the last week. the calendar week before.

And the same for the month and year.

I thins `SUB_DATE` is not the right way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for. If you want all records that have an onlineDate that falls into last week (for example), your logic is exactly right. How is what you have now not working?

Comment: It's not very clear from your question do you need an exact moment a week, month and year ago or date ranges?

Comment: I need, for example, the last week.
with this I get the current week
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE WEEK(artists.onlineDate, 3) = WEEK(CURDATE(), 3)
But I need the week before, from monday to sunday, not 7 days back.

Comment: I got it work now, it seems to just adding a "-1" WEEK(artists.onlineDate, 3) = WEEK(CURDATE(), 3) -1
so I get the calender week before

Answer (score 3):

OK I found what I was looking for at:

[MySQL Query to select data from last week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week)

```
SELECT * FROM testwoche 
 WHERE WEEK (datum, 3) = WEEK(current_date, 3) - 1 
   AND YEAR(datum) = YEAR(current_date) ORDER BY datum DESC
```

same for month

```
SELECT * FROM testwoche 
 WHERE month (datum) = month(current_date) - 1 
  AND YEAR(datum) = YEAR(current_date) 
ORDER BY datum DESC
```

This gives back the last week from monday to sunday and the last month

Thanks everybody for helping!

Comment: Make sure you check this answer as accepted to help future visitors.

Comment: As far as I checked it with my little mySQL knowledge, the results are exactly what I need.

Comment: One problem with this query for "last month" is that it won't work when it's run January to get data for December, which is not in the current year, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the SUBTIME function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime

I haven't had time to really test it, but I think you get the idea:

Yesterday:

```
 SELECT * FROM artists WHERE DATE(artists.onlineDate) = SUBTIME(CURDATE(),'1 0:0:0');
```

Last Week

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE WEEK(artists.onlineDate, 3) = WEEK(SUBTIME(CURDATE(),'7 0:0:0'), 3)
```

Last Month

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE MONTH(artists.onlineDate) = MONTH(SUBTIME(CURDATE(),'31 0:0:0'))
```

Last Year

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE YEAR(artists.onlineDate) = YEAR(SUBTIME(CURDATE(),'365 0:0:0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific week/month/year (which still works when your db contains several years worth of data and when your current time is the start of a new year), this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM testwoche WHERE 
((YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(datum)))*52-WEEK(datum,3)+WEEK(CURDATE(),3) = 1;
```

If you want two weeks ago, you could change it to `=2` (if you want current week, from Monday to current day: `=0`). If you want last month, you change the `WEEK` function to `MONTH`.