# How to select row of last week, last month and last year form mysql database table

Tags: mysql, sql

What I need is exact: Query for get records of between from current date to previous week OR previous month OR previous year.

```
SELECT * FROM `job` as j WHERE j.`created_at` <= LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Ex. Currently running 08(august) month then i want to get records inserted between 07(july) to 08(august) months

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL results yesterday, last week, last month and last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529899/mysql-results-yesterday-last-week-last-month-and-last-year)

Comment: Please define what *you* mean by "Last Week, Last Month, Last Year old data rows".

Comment: Give example of input and expected output

Comment: I mean sir, 
I want to get records who is added before one week OR one month OR one year.
Mean get records between today to from previous week, month or year
Ex. Currently 08 months. I want records between 07 to 08

Comment: Check this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064687/mysql-select-all-rows-from-last-month-until-now-1-month-for-comparative-p

Answer (score 0):

I used this on some of my projects , is selecting 7 days back up untill "today" now() , you can "Tweak" your interval there ...

You can also [check the examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064820/2307600) , how to get the first day and the last day of the month so you will be able to make the select query ...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE store_date >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY ORDER BY store_date DESC
```