# Is INTERVAL required for datetime arithmetic in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

Is it always necessary to use the `interval` function in MySQL when using math to create relative dates?

I use `Date()-Weekday(Date())` in MS-Access 2010 and tried `curdate() - dayofweek(curdate())` in MySQL.  I got some obscure number, and after searching found [this StackOver answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week) that accomplishes what I want to.

After reading [this support article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) I want to be sure I understand this right--any time I want to do simple math with date functions, I *have* to use the interval function and declare what unit of time I want to work with?

If I don't use the interval function, is there any use for the number I get from `curdate() - dayofweek(curdate())`?

I've never used `interval` before, and I'm just used to MS products treating date format and number format as one in the same.  Looking for some clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is *no* use for the number you got back from `curdate() - dayofweek(curdate())`.

```
SELECT curdate() - dayofweek(curdate())

+----------------------------------+
| curdate() - dayofweek(curdate()) |
+----------------------------------+
|                         20140097 |
+----------------------------------+
```

What you're looking at there is the result of the number `20140103` minus the number `6` and it bears no resemblance to any usable date:

```
> select 20140103 - 6;
+--------------+
| 20140103 - 6 |
+--------------+
|     20140097 |
+--------------+
```

Because you didn't use `INTERVAL`, MySQL appears to have cast the date `2014-01-03` into the number `20140103` and the result when subtracting the current weekday (6) is nonsense. (I'm actually surprised that happened - I would have expected an error or a different result<sup>1</sup>).

You *do* need to use the `INTERVAL` specifier for simple arithmetic or when using many of [MySQL's date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

In some cases you could get around using `INTERVAL` if you converted values to and from integers as Unix timestamps via `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime), FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)`.  It's tricky to get right though and I recommend using the real date/time functions to work with actual `DATE/DATETIME` values whenever possible.

```
select curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) DAY;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) DAY |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2013-12-28                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*That's more like it* :)

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't have an explanation for the casting behavior that occurred, because I would have expected this instead. Needless to say though, it's not something you should be using or relying on:

```
SELECT CAST('2014-01-03' AS UNSIGNED);
+------------------------------+
| CAST('2014-01-03' AS UNSIGNED) |
+------------------------------+
|                         2014 |
+------------------------------+
```

... Actually, here it is casting a `DATE` to an unsigned `INTEGER`:

```
SELECT CAST(STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d') AS UNSIGNED);
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d') AS UNSIGNED) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                20140103 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```