# SQL select current week/last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way of selecting rows based on:

- Current week (S-S)
- Previous week (S-S)

The problem I'm having is selecting specifically from **Sunday-Sunday**.

At the moment I'm using:

```
SELECT SUM(time) 
FROM `time` 
WHERE `projectid` = '$pid' && created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Does `&&` really work in MySQL as an replacement for `AND`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [Yes, though it weirds me out to see it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)

Comment: But woe unto those who get in the habit of using `||` instead of `OR` and suddenly find themselves concatenating everything in when they move to another RDBMS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does have a [`WEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function that you can use:

```
SELECT SUM(time) 
FROM `time` 
WHERE
    `projectid` = '$pid'
    AND created > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
    AND WEEK(created) IN (WEEK(NOW()), WEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
```

## Notes

The first condition (`created > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK`) is needed to get all the data of the current and previous weeks first and then restrict for the two weeks you are interested in. Otherwise, if you had enough data, you would get the aggregation of all data of the corresponding weeks *of every year in your table*. It also has the added benefit of allowing the query to use an index on that field.

You also need to use "`WEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`" due to the first week of the year. Otherwise, `WEEK(NOW()) - 1` would have sufficed