# how to find the bigger date among two dates in a week by using mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, birt

i have two dates in the same week i want to know which is the highest date among those two dates 
for example 3/24/2014 and 3/27/2014 are the two dates in same week i want to know which is the bigger date among these two i.e 3/27/2014

what function should i use to get this result.

i tried with some of the question and answers in this link it did not work out
[MySQL Query to select data from last week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week)

Answer (score 0):

Might be you want this

```
SELECT max(date) FROM table_name
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Comment: Can you explain what is your requirements?

Comment: 02/march/2014------test value 1    02/march/2014------test value 2                                           02/march/2014------test value 3                                            03/march/2014------test value 4                                      03/march/2014------test value 5                                        now if i create a view it should show me only these values (i.e only the latest values in the week)03/march/2014------test value 4                           03/march/2014------test value 5

Comment: Can you post your requirements in question?