# Puling out data from the table from last week

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM school WHERE  WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) ";
```

This query that i have currently in my code is getting me data from the current week starting from Monday. How can i get data from the table from last week or the week before. I have tried changing now to last week or currentweek.

any ideas is it possible to use weekofyear(()) and tweak it

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week

Comment: would it be possible to use weekofyear(now()) but tweak it to get last week s data

Comment: Sure, add 53 and take the remainder of dividing by 54: `MOD(WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) + 53, 54)`

Comment: Also note that any solution where you compare `WEEKOFYEAR` values is highly unreliable as you do not take the year into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some date shift right in mysql, replace NOW() with

```
NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

there is also date_sub for subtracting

```
date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $qry = "SELECT * FROM school WHERE studId = $sessionId AND studentId = $student
    AND date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
    AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY"
```