# Select statement to display data for this week

Tags: .net, vb.net

i want to show data from the database in list view , but i want to show the data for this week only , i have this statement for get the current month :

```
Public Sub showlistview()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM pay_pretalk WHERE MONTH(sdate)= date(NOW())", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myrow As DataRow
        For Each myrow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(5))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(6))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(7))
        Next
End Sub
```

i tried many thing but nothing work :(

how i can do this for the current week ??

Comment: its pretty simple. you use the DATEADD() and subtract 7 days from GETDATE() and add a condition to select records between that formula and GETDATE() - this will show the data for the past 7 days. so you need to clarify is this is what you mean or something else...

Comment: Probably something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090065/242584

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM pay_pretalk WHERE DatePart(week,sdate)=  DatePart(week,GETDATE())
```

But beware, keeping functions in the where clause is not very efficient. If you could use a function or stored procedure, you could save the week number for the RHS of comparison in a variable and use it in the query.

Note: Since you did not mention the database, I assumed it to be MS SQL.