# Selecting mysql records for next week

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the MySQL query to select date records that fall within the next week using Sunday - Saturday as the format for the week.

So in other words, I'm not looking to get the dates a week from today, I'm looking to get the dates that fall within Sunday - Saturday of the next week.

I found this: [MySQL Query to select data from last week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week) and it works for the previous week from Sunday - Saturday but I'm not sure how to tweak this to get the dates for the next week.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Sorry about that. The link I provided to the other example is basically the same idea that I want to do except in the example, they get the previous week, while I'm looking to get the next week (Sunday - Saturday).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
date > date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL(7-dayofweek(curdate()))DAY) 
AND date <= date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL(14- dayofweek(curdate()))DAY)
```

Comment: dateofweek is not a function,among other things.

Comment: you are right, sorry syntax error , I've corrected it
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: This one isn't working for me. There's some missing parentheses in your code but even when I fix them I still don't get the next weeks dates

Comment: phillymatt 
sorry, it had syntax errors, I wanted to show the algorithm.
I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE WEEK(YourDateField, 6) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY, 6)
```

for selecting recods of next week (starting with sunday)
Weeks count is 1 to 53 with first week of the year having at least 4 days in the year