# How can I get the user created in the last week in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I write the sql like this:

```
Select  * from SYS_USER where YEARWEEK(date_format(createtime,'%Y-%m-%d')) = YEARWEEK(now());
```

But at 2015-8-31,I run the sql and find the 2015-8-30 and 2015-8-31 is in the same week.In fact,it is in the different week in my calendar.In my calendar,the first day of week is monday,not sunday.How to change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090065/3011902

If you would rather do it in relation to a specific day, you can do this:

```
select id
from table
where date >= "$sunday-date" + interval 7 DAY
```

From the same source.

I recommend doing a thorough Google search before posting questions next time ;)

Comment: Not that kind of week

Comment: Updated answer. Don't be so quick to donwvote.