# Get last 5 week range

Tags: sql-server

I need to load info from the last five weeks in five seperate lists, no matter what date. So this week, I'll need the last 5 weeks before this one. Next week I'll need the last 5 weeks before that one, which includes this one. If this makes sense and doesn't confuse you?

So basically:

```
..BETWEEN '2015-09-21' AND '2015-09-27'
```

Has to be replaced with:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6)
```

This works just fine, same for the second week:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,14,GETDATE()),0) AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,14,GETDATE()),6)
```

**BUT** from then on, it doesn't work anymore. I get different results than when I add the date manually.

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,21,GETDATE()),0) AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,21,GETDATE()),6)
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Comment: Presumably you are using SQL Server.  You should tag the question as such.

Comment: check this link it will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week

Comment: What result do you get? Does the query `SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,21,GETDATE()),0), DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,21,GETDATE()),6)` return something unexpected?

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov Then I get the right date range from 3 weeks ago, so I'm using correct data yet it shows not all results

Comment: @Greg, do you have the time part in your column or is there only date? Did you try to add 7 days instead of 6? `DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,21,GETDATE()),7)`

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov I indeed have the time part when I execute that line. So I assume when it said `2015-09-27 00:00:00` it didn't count results from that day? I replaced 6 with 7 and that does indeed work! But the first two weeks that worked with 6 have different results now with 7

Comment: Probably, in first two weeks you don't have any results on Sunday. For the `date` type `2015-09-27 00:00:00` will count all results, but not for the `datetime` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `BETWEEN` for the `datetime` data type you should add **7** days to the beginning of a week to find the end of that week

```
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,21,GETDATE()),7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a similar code instead of setting `number` manually:

```
DECLARE @TestDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WeekNumber AS INTEGER

-- previous 5 weeks
SELECT @TestDate = GETDATE()
SELECT @WeekNumber = -5

WHILE @WeekNumber < 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @TestDate,
        @WeekNumber,
        DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekNumber, @TestDate)), 0) AS StartDate,
        DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekNumber, @TestDate)), 6) AS EndDate

    SELECT @WeekNumber = @WeekNumber + 1

END

-- previous 5 weeks from next wednesday
SELECT @TestDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())
SELECT @WeekNumber = -5

WHILE @WeekNumber < 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @TestDate,
        @WeekNumber,
        DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekNumber, @TestDate)), 0) AS StartDate,
        DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekNumber, @TestDate)), 6) AS EndDate

    SELECT @WeekNumber = @WeekNumber + 1

END
```

Please note that the contents of `WHILE` loop doesn't change. I use the same code to extract info about two different dates.