# In sqlserver how to find last before week data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying the below query, but it's output comes last 2 weeks data, but I need only last before week data only.

```
select * from tablename where createddate>=DATEADD(WEEK,-2, GETDATE()) ;
```

Comment: Do you need data of the week before the last week only?

Comment: You should use `where createddate <= DATEADD(WEEK,-2, GETDATE()) ;` for data before last week..

Comment: `|CURRENT WEEK | PREVIOUS WEEK | PREVIOUS PREVIOUS WEEK |` ... which weeks do you want in your result set?

Comment: i need  previous previous week data

Comment: And do you mean in in the last full week (eg Sunday to Saturday / Monday to Sunday) ?

Comment: ...or do you mean the last 7 days, regardless of which day on which we begin?

Comment: ..or do you want all records before the last week..? i.e. All records excluding the last week and current week.?

Comment: today date is 20-5-16,i need 6-5-16 to 13-5-16 this week all  records , but with  out using dates i need that output.

Comment: Huh?  I just checked a calendar and these dates don't make any sense to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Query to select data from last week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week)

Comment: The answer below by TIm is the correct answer as per your requirement. Try and run the SQL.

Comment: i am telling just example that date sir ,in my database not using that dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one your comments I found that the week you are talking about starts from Friday, so you need to add up those gap days into your condition

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE createddate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 4 ,DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE())), 4)
AND createddate < DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 4 ,DATEADD(WEEK, 0, GETDATE())), 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add another condition to your `WHERE` clause to restrict to earlier than the week before last:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE createddate >= DATEADD(WEEK,-2, GETDATE()) AND
      createddate < DATEADD(WEEK,-1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: i this case only last week data will geting

Comment: This answer will give you a 7-day window starting 21 days (3 weeks) before now and ending 14 days (2 weeks) before now.

Comment: ya its coming  ,but  last week data is also is there. i need only that 2nd week data.

Comment: in this case today to 13th may results is coming.but i need 13th to 6th may resluts

Comment: I disagree.  This should exclude records from the previous 7 days, while including the week prior to that.

Comment: is there any other query  to this ?

Answer (score -1):

this code is currect answer for my quation,

---

```
 select * from dbo_OrdersCompleteView1 where  S2_DateTimeOrederLines between DATEADD(WEEK,-2, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE());
```