# List all the record 1 week between the current date (Now)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In this post, i want to know how to list a record between one week from current date. It means TODAY is current date (13june) and I want to select all the record 1 week between it. It means from 6june till NOW (current date 13/june). And it will continuously display record between one week from current date. I have found and read a post from StackOverflow, seem none of it are working for me.

```
select * from parcel where date_recieve between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

Comment: Since you tagged as php, where is that and the API used to connect with? Given you're posting comments under answers given but none have worked for you. I sure hope you're paying attention to comments here and not just answering to answers only, because magic only happens in the movies.

Comment: *Yoohoo!!!!* up here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: sorry i was read the others solved post.. it related to my attribute type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from parcel where date_recieve between date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and curdate();
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 sec)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to get last week records

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$afterDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 Days')); 

$query = "select * from parcel where date_recieve between '$afterDate' and '$now' " ;       
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: No data available in table.. doesnt works too

Comment: @aquilina this is working for me ... any error you are getting ??

Comment: Nope it doesnt appear any error.

Comment: there must be any other error with your code as your  `select * from parcel where date_recieve between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();` is also working for me

Comment: @aquilina use `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` to  get errors from query, see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week picked from this I think

Comment: Yes this works 4 me

Comment: it should work for SO questionnaire

Comment: It doesnt show any result in my SQL.. SELECT * FROM parcel
WHERE date_recieve >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date_recieve < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY

Comment: Is it executing correctly ? If yes than parcel  table have not the exact data.

Comment: Yes it executing correctly but doesnt display any data. MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: Can you please share your table with structure and data?

Comment: here is it http://prntscr.com/bftwfl

Comment: I want data and structure so that I can execute it on my local.

Comment: @aquilina why on earth are you using VARCHAR for date(times)??? No wonder it doesn't work. Use MySQL's types for this and do pay attention to comments left under your question as I have earlier.

Comment: -- Table structure for table `add_parcel`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_parcel` (
  `parcel_id` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parcel_num` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `date_recieve` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `date_collect` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `recieve_time` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `collect_time` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `sender_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `send_to` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parcel_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;

Comment: @Fred -ii- yah im using manually key in the date.

Comment: Please run below query ----   ALTER TABLE `add_parcel` CHANGE `date_recieve` `date_recieve` DATE NOT NULL, CHANGE `date_collect` `date_collect` DATE NOT NULL, CHANGE `recieve_time` `recieve_time` TIME NOT NULL, CHANGE `collect_time` `collect_time` TIME NOT NULL;

Comment: Im already make a changing about the date type.. and it working now. Thank you