# H2 find records from the last Monday to now

Tags: sql, h2

I my java spring mvc application, I used `H2` as database

I have a table like below:

```
id  date
2   2011-05-14 09:17:25
5   2011-05-16 09:17:25
6   2011-05-17 09:17:25
8   2011-05-20 09:17:25
15  2011-05-22 09:17:25
```

I need to extract the records which their date field is between last Monday to now.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week), but i don't know how would be the equivalent in `h2`.
Is it even possible to write such query in `H2`?