# SQL : retrieve top 7 of entries added in the past week

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, search

I’m new to SQL and I need some help for a query that should return a top of occurrences sorted by date.

Actually I have a table to which are added searches done by users alongside the date of search (column is in the DATETIME format).
What I would like to do is to create a list of « Trending searches » that would show the top 7 searches done over the past week (Sunday to Sunday for example) but I’m unsure where to start.

I’ve heard of the DATEPART function but I don’t know how to use it alongside a top 7 occurrences.

Thanks in advance for your help and have a nice day !

Comment: Done, it concern SQL server

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
declare @lastweek datetime
declare @now datetime
set @now = getdate()
set @lastweek = dateadd(day,-7,@now)


SELECT COUNT(g.searchTerm) AS appearanceCount, g.searchTerm FROM DesiredTable AS g
WHERE g.DateSearched  BETWEEN @lastweek AND @now
GROUP BY(GameTypeId)
ORDER BY (appearanceCount) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The mention of `datepart()` suggests SQL Server.  If so, you can do:

```
select top (7) s.searchTerm, count(*)
from searches s
where s.searchTime >= dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
group by s.searchTerm
order by count(*) desc;
```

This gets the last 7 days to the current time.

If you want the last week, a pretty simple `where` is:

```
where datediff(week, s.searchTime, getdate()) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solvable pretty easy with mysql. You are trying to do multiple things, as far as I understood:

**1. Get searches from last week**

With DATETIME fields there are pretty easy ways to extract the week of the year:

```
SELECT id FROM searches 
WHERE searchDate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND searchDate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week).

**2. Get the top 7 most frequent ones**

Secondly you said that you want to have the top 7 searches, which translate into *most frequent occurring search terms*. In other words: You need to group identical search terms together and count them:

```
SELECT count(id), searchTerm FROM searches 
WHERE searchDate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND searchDate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
GROUP BY searchTerm
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition:
To get the first n (here 7) rows use rownum<=7.
Like this (added to Gegenwinds solution):

```
SELECT result.* FROM 
(SELECT count(id), searchTerm FROM searches 
WHERE searchDate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND searchDate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
GROUP BY searchTerm) result
ORDER BY count(id) DESC
WHERE rownum<= 7
```