# how to get current week and last week record in same table with different rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi Everyone i am writing mysql query for getting current week and last week data in same table with different rows expected output i have mention below also i need last week data based on current week selection. current week data i am getting based on select date but didn't know how to get last week date, please help me out.

| date | total_cars | online_hours | trips |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| current_week | 20 | 100 | 200 |
| last_week | 10 | 60 | 80 |

**query for current week record**

```
SELECT cd.date, COUNT( cd.car_number) as total_cars, sum(cd.trips) as total_trips,
sum(cd.online_hours) as online_hours
FROM fleet_car_dash_daily as cd
WHERE cd.team_id= 1 and cd.date BETWEEN '2022-04-04' and '2022-04-10'
```

Comment: hi, try to do a two separate query for this week and last week then use union

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089960/mysql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week

Comment: @fonz thanks i have use union this is help for me

Comment: welcome, glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

This can also help:

```
SELECT cd.date, COUNT( cd.car_number) as total_cars, sum(cd.trips) as total_trips,
sum(cd.online_hours) as online_hours
FROM fleet_car_dash_daily as cd
WHERE cd.team_id= 1 and cd.date BETWEEN '2022-04-04' - INTERVAL 7 DAY and '2022-04-10'
GROUP BY WEEK(cd.date)
ORDER BY WEEK(cd.date);
```